# Samba4 internal DNS and isc-dhcp zone update

Tags: samba, domain-controller, internal-dns, samba4, isc-dhcp

Could anybody explain, how to solve this problem with internal samba4 DNS and dynamic zone updates from `isc-dhcp`?

In the logs I have:

> dhcpd: Unable to add reverse map from 170.5.168.192.in-addr.arpa. to
>   dus-ws-21a.nmedia.local: tsig verify failure

Samba4 works as Domain Controller well, I only get errors from zone updates. But Google gives nothing.

I tried to follow this manual: [ISC DHCPd: Dynamic DNS updates against secure Microsoft DNS](http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2011/02/isc-dhcpd-dynamic-dns-updates-against-secure-microsoft-dns/), but I have:

> execute: /root/shell/dhcp-dyndns.sh exit status 512

How to solve this problem?